# drop-down selecting current data from database at update page

Tags: php, mysql, drop-down-menu

When I am choosing Category at add_content.php, I am using code below and it's working.

```
<select name="category"><?php

$q=mysql_query("select * from categories where sub='0' order by desc");
while ($maincategory=mysql_fetch_array($q)){

    echo "
    <option style=background-color:#BCE77C; value=$maincategory[id]>$maincategory[title]</b></option>";

$q1=mysql_query("select  * from categories where sub='".$maincategory['id']."' order by desc");
while ($subcategory=mysql_fetch_array($q1)){

    echo "<option value=$subcategory[id]>--$subcategory[title]</option>";
    }

}

?></select>
```

*

Right now I am working on edit_content.php.
I want the current category pre-selected from database.

What I should do; connecting the content datebase in order to get current ID, for example;

```
        // get the category the post is assigned to
        $query = mysql_query("SELECT category FROM article");
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
            $chosenCategory = $row['id'];
        }
```

like that. But I can't go further. I appreciate your helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just check while echoing, if the value is equal to chosen value.

First get the id

```
 // get the category the post is assigned to
        $query = mysql_query("SELECT category FROM article");
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
            $chosenCategory = $row['id'];
        }
```

Then use the selected attribute of option tag

```
    <select name="category"><?php

    $q=mysql_query("select * from categories where sub='0' order by desc");
    while ($maincategory=mysql_fetch_array($q)){
    if($maincategory[id] == $chosenCategory)
{
        echo "<option style=background-color:#BCE77C; value=$maincategory[id] selected>$maincategory[title]</b></option>";
}
else
{
echo "<option style=background-color:#BCE77C; value=$maincategory[id]>$maincategory[title]</b></option>";

}

    }

    ?></select>
```

Comment: but what happened to my subcategories? and also it doesnt preselect main category neighter.

Comment: You can apply the same logic to subcategories, compare the subcategory id with current id while echoing. Check the following site for selected attribute http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_option_selected.asp